# Solving Equation with Reduced Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have the matrix in reduced row echelon form as:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1 &-1 & -1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

So, how do we find solutions based on this form?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for you to learn how to make your question easier to read

Comment: Didn't find the desired solution there :(

Comment: @User32139202 I edited for you, and made the assumption that the fourth column is augmented. Let me know if this is not right! By the by, you could have found this information in the first answer of J. W. Tanner's link (titled: Matrices), in point 4 of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach: Now we have
$$x+z = \frac{1}{2}, \: y-z=-\frac{1}{2}$$
this can also be written as
$$x = \frac{1}{2}-z, \: y = -\frac{1}{2}+z$$ and technically $z=z$ (this is obvious but just how I would think about it). Notice we only have two equations for three variables, so we will have infinitely many solutions. Our solutions are $\{(\frac{1}{2}-\lambda, -\frac{1}{2}+\lambda, \lambda): \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$